# Write a LISP code that prints the even number from a list of 10 values

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a beginner in lisp language so kindly tell me how to make a lisp of 10 variables and print even numbers from list I try this

```
(write (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
terpri
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: (write (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
terpri

Comment: `terpri` is a function; you must call it: `(terpri)`. Otherwise you're referencing a `terpri` variable, which almost certainly doesn't exist.

Comment: try (evenp 1) and (evenp 2), then see (remove-if 'stringp '("a" 0)) then try to mix things up

Answer (score 1):

You can create the list using `list` or quote:

```lisp
(list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 10)
```

To filter out non-even elements, you can use `remove-if-not`, `remove-if` or `loop` macro:

```lisp
(remove-if-not #'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(remove-if #'oddp '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(loop for x in '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
      when (evenp x)
      collect x)
```

All three return

```
(2 4 6 8 10)
```

To print elements of the list, you can iterate over the list with `dolist`:

```lisp
(setf my-list (remove-if-not #'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)))
(dolist (x my-list) (print x))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `loop` macro:

```lisp
(loop for i in my-list
      when (evenp i)
      do (print i))
```